# OpenShift Hello World java vertical

Tags: java, openshift, vert.x

I'm trying to create a simple "Hello World" vertx java application on OpenShift, but somehow my class can not be found/run.

I have created a new app on OpenShift and cloned the git repository, from there I have added my sample *Test.java* class.

Also I have added to the */configuration/vertx.env* file

```
export vertx_module=com.test~project~1.0
```

in my pom.xml I have

```
<artifactId>project</artifactId>
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<version>1.0</version>
```

I also tried and added the following to the /mods/mod.json file

```
{
  "main": "com.test.project.Test"
}
```

....
What am I missing, or otherwise said, how should be the project structured (on OpenShift) in order to make vertx run my simple *Test.class* ?

Or is there maybe an additional maven step that must be taken inside the *pom.xml*?

Comment: Have you read through this section of the Developer Portal? https://developers.openshift.com/en/vertx-overview.html

Comment: Sure I did ... but I was unable to find a java example. The given prototype project uses javascript. Additionally there seem to be a maven step not documented as there is only a TODO on the bottom of this page: https://github.com/vert-x/openshift-cartridge. However it shouldn't be hard to provide a simple HelloWorld java vertx example for OpenShift or even a template project of this kind to make the start easier. PS: I'm not using Eclipse (there seem to be a plugin available) but Idea which doesn't support OpenShift integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok ... it seems that currently the vertx catridge doesn't run a maven build after `git push`. This is somehow broken (at least for Java).

To get your Java module running you need to log into your app via OpenShift console and then:

1. run the maven build for your vertx java module (this will put the correct files into the maven `.m2` folder and vertx will find it). Files are stored in: `~/app-root/repo`
2. restart vertx:

   ```
   sh ~/vertx/bin/control restart
   ```

Hopefully will OpenShift automate this steps in the future.

Comment: Perhaps you could add these steps as [build action hooks](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-action-hooks.html#_build_action_hooks) so that they _do_ execute on a `git push`.